# In multi thread download program only one backgroundthread is working and next one throwing the operation time out exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, timeout, backgroundworker, operation

I am trying to download a file with multi backgroundworkers.

I have the below code in Download method,

```
     private static CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();
    public static void Download(string url, string from, string to, string method, string fileName)
    {
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = method;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.Timeout = 12000;
        req.CookieContainer = c;
        req.AddRange(Convert.ToInt32(from), Convert.ToInt32(to));
        using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine((int)res.StatusCode + " ");
            using (Stream output = res.GetResponseStream())
            {
                  using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                    int len;
                     while ((len = output.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        file.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                        //Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}", fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Complated!");
     }
```

each BackgroundWorker should call this, but only the first BackGroundWorker is working and the next one throwing the "The operation timeout" exception

*currently Second Worker is calling after the complete execution of the first worker only, but i want to make this multi threaded app*

**Can any one help me please....**

please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks,
Srinivas

---------------------Update----------------------------------------

Now added a shared cookie and it is allowing only 2 threads one after one, means after the first download then it is trying to download the next one.
How can i make it symultanious download?

**Can any one help  me please....**

Thanks
Srini

Comment: Perhaps the server only accepts one connection per client. Thus timing out the other connections.

Comment: Hello 
Mr. Michael,
Thanks for showing interest on my question, 
I tried the same file with IDM and it is doing a multi threaded download. Also not only that file, all files are downloaded through only one thread in my application!!

Comment: Can we see how you go multithreading? Maybe the issue is there

Comment: I dont think so, because when I add a simple for loop to print the parsed filename in the Download method, then I could see all the filenames printing on the console. When I use the above code in download method then i could see only one file name at once. Please correct me if my diagnostic is wrong!

Comment: HTTP protocol allows only 2 concurrent HTTP requests from any single point of origin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> currently Second Worker is calling after the complete execution of the first worker only

No, that's most certainly the wrong diagnostic.  Because if that was the case then the second worker would not call req.GetResponse() until the first worker was done.  So could not timeout immediately.

*Something* is throttling the number of concurrent http requests you can start at the same time.  The server itself is certainly high on the list of candidates, particularly the kind of server that supplies the kind of data where this kind of technique makes sense.  They certainly protect themselves against this.  That another program can bypass this doesn't otherwise prove anything, it could do something nasty to defeat the server's detection algorithm like spoofing the IP address (I'm reaching).  Lots of other candidates, like a proxy server or something silly in the anti-malware.

Do verify the server's terms of usage statement, pretty unlikely that the server owner is happy about you doing this.

Comment: Hello Mr. Hans Passant,

Comment: Hello Mr. Hans Passant, Thank you for your reply. I agree with you. But can you please tell me how can I resolve this issue? (multithread download of any file). It would be great if you suggest with an example. Thanks...

Comment: You will have to find the *something* that is throttling you.  Start by contacting the web site owner, talk to your local LAN administrator next.

Comment: HTTP protocol allows only 2 concurrent HTTP requests from any single point of origin...